# Why does this Blofeld inspired character have six robotic legs? (in Thunderbirds - puppet style Elle King music video)

Tags: james-bond

In the puppet-animated James Bond inspired video for the Elle King song "Under the influence" we see a Blofeld inspired character with six robotic legs.

Is this purely the product of the animator's imagination, or is it a reference to some other villain, perhaps from a Thunderbirds - puppet style animation?

See video here

Comment: I don't recognise it as a character type from any of the Anderson supermarionation series, so it's unlikely to be connected directly with the animation style. However there's a handful of villains like that: Dr Arliss Loveless is the first that springs to mind.